# disable CONNECT in squid proxy

Tags: proxy, squid, tunneling

I have a requirement to disable tunneling through squid proxy. This is the first time I am setting up the proxy and can't seem to find much information on disabling CONNECT/tunneling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have this line in your *squid.conf*:

`acl CONNECT method CONNECT`

then add this line on top of the `http_access` block:

`http_access deny CONNECT`

then restart your squid.

Third, you're probably ***doing some nasty stuff, stop it.***